# How to insert multiple Items in two table in one go?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, e-commerce

I have One OrderDetails Table another is Order table, i am creating an API where from frontend developer will be sending multiple orders i want to save all product and also the user id who had ordered

I created Two Table One is Order another is OrderDetails And Using Dotnet core for creating API i am stuck becuase i dont know how to proceed after this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApiProject.Models
{
    public class ServiceCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
        public string ServiceTitle { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        public Service Service { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
// Order Table Which has reference from ServiceCategory
// Fyi Servicecategory Is my product which user will be adding to cart

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApiProject.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ServiceCategory ServiceCategories { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double AmountOfProduct { get; set; }
        public double DiscountOnProduct { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderDetails> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}

//OrderDetails
// This is my order details table where i am going to save my user info and //order info which has been ordered
using System;
using WebApiProject.API.Models;

namespace WebApiProject.Models
{
    public class OrderDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfPurchase { get; set; }
        public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now i have an issue that i created Model and ran the migration now I don't know how to use this in repository or how I will create a DTO for this which I can use it while testing through postman

Please help any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried BTW? post that here

Comment: I mentioned That i am stucked because i dont know how to proceed after creating models and adding migrations i havent proceed i need to know how to implement this feature

Comment: So first: I think your tables are a bit wrong. If you think like a normal shopping cart: An `Order` contains one or more `Products`, Since you don't know how many products an order may have, you need another table to store: Product and Order (often as a composed PK/FK). Your `OrderDetails` page is this one. You need to add the product to it. Then you can start writing the API for it.

Comment: There are multiple tutorials on shop carts apps over the web.. for instance you could look at the Music Store app: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/MusicStore/samples/MusicStore/Models. It's too broad of a question and we can't basically teach you all of the involved stuff in here.